# Windows Communication Foundation (WCF)

Tags: wcf, asmx

Why we are going for WCF when web services (ASMX) exist ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a nice article that you can look at

[Comparing ASP.NET Web Services to WCF Based on Development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa738737.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

- WCF supports protocols beyond HTTP (TCP and MSMQ come to mind) and message formats beyond XML, so it could be used for tasks they are unsuitable e.g. because these tasks require better performance.
- WCF could be self-hosted so no need for hosting in IIS.
- WCF supports preserving service object state between calls.

Answer (score 1):

Another rather interesting and thoughtful comparison:

http://www.keithelder.net/blog/archive/2008/10/17/WCF-vs-ASMX-WebServices.aspx

Download the PowerPoint and have a look at it - also, watch [Keith's DotNetRocks TV](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=135) appearance for a great screencast intro to WCF and its advantages over ASMX.

Marc

Answer (score 0):

Web services require use of HTTP protocol on standard HTTP ports, right?  WCF is more flexible.  It can be based on HTTP, TCP, UDP and such.  It allows you to design an application with network connectivity without caring so much about the protocol used.  Then you can more easily switch the network protocol without affecting the application.